# What happen when I change Stripe account (client_id, stripe public key, stripe secret key)

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on a website that use Stripe for payment, use Ruby: 2.5.8 Rails: 4.2 . Website was working for a long time and now the product owner wants to change to another Stripe account. So I update CLIENT_ID, STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY, STRIPE_SECRET_KEY to new Stripe account.
And I encounter many errors (on test version):

- undefined method `subscriptions' for #Stripe::Customer:************ when I create a new provider
- SMTP To address may not be blank [] when send email to a new provider
- undefined method 'sources' for #Stripe::Customer:************ when I update a card information (test on VISA)
- ....

I found many discussion about my errors but they are independently. In my case, I think that I was miss something about the Stripe account transfer?
Can you explain for me about the Stripe account transfer or some documents about that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was fixed. The answer is API version: old Stripe Account uses API version 2017-06-05 and default API version of new account is latest (2020-08-27).
In 2020-08-27 version, the Customer API doesn't have sources, subscriptions,.. by default. So I was downgrade API by add `stripe_version` [document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning) (but you can use new API version with `expand` [document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) )

Answer (score 0):

None of the objects that exist in the old Stripe Account exist in the new Stripe Account, so that's likely the issue here.

Comment: I read [document](https://support.stripe.com/questions/copy-existing-account-data-to-a-new-stripe-account). I know that can copy data, but I don't know how to copy

Comment: You have to reach out to Support, but they can only copy Customers and payment methods, nothing else.  https://support.stripe.com/contact/email